# Customize \subsection title

Tags: titlesec

I'm going crazy! I would like to customize the title of the \subsection. The numbering should be 1.1 ... 1.2 ... 1.3 ... etc. Also I would like to set the distance between the number and the description to be about 35mm. Is it possible? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large}

\begin{document}

\subsection{First Section}

\subsection{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the body of your document skip over `\section` and go straight to `\subsection`?

Comment: Okay, you're right. I mostly need \subsection, but if you can teach me for \section as well better yet. Thank you.

Comment: Put `\section{some title}` before your first`\subsection`.

Comment: How do you need the section-level headers to be formatted?

Comment: For the custom numbering, see Turion's answer to this post:
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200437/numbering-sections-subsections-etc-manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200437/numbering-sections-subsections-etc-manually) For the number-title spacing, see Werner's answer to this post:
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25989/spacing-in-headline-between-number-and-text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25989/spacing-in-headline-between-number-and-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want. The divisional ordering for the `article` class is (forgetting about `\part`) `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, etc. Do you only want `\subsection` with no `\section`?

If you want both `\section` and `\subsection` then put a `\section{some section title}` before any `\subsection`.

If you only want `\subsection` with numbering 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc then change the printing of the subsection counter. Put the following in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{1.\arabic{subsection}}
```

**EDIT**

The following is a more flexible way. Among other things the `\section` command increments the section number. Also by default the section number is placed before the number of a subsection.

Define a command to increment the section number, called say `\upsecnum` and use this before a block of subsections.

For example:

```
% subsecprob.tex  SE 580322
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\upsecnum}{\refstepcounter{section}}

\begin{document}

\upsecnum       % start a subsection block
\subsection{One}
\subsection{Two}
\subsection{Three} \label{subsec}
Now start a new block of subsections. \verb|\upsecnum|

\upsecnum
\subsection{Uno}
\subsection{Duo}
\subsection{Tres}
The third subsection overall is \ref{subsec}.

\setcounter{section}{0} % reinitialise section numbering
\section{A section}

\subsection{Eins}
\subsection{Zwei}
\subsection{Drei}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!