# How to write Subsection 1.1 after Section 2

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to create a subsection of a different section in my document but I can't achieve that, no matter what I do. Basically I want the `\subsection` to be a subsection of the first section in my document, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\section{Section 1}
% some lines

\newpage
\section{Section 2}
% more lines

\newpage
\subsection{Section 1.1 (subsection of Section 1)}
```

The `\subsection` is always a subsection of Section 2 and I can't get it to be of Section 1. 
 (that way of subsectioning sounds stupid but I want to make a comparison between Section 1 and Section 2 so I have to put them right after each other, then the subsections come later) 
 Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why should you want a subsection of "Section 2" being numbered as "1.1 Section 1.1" ?
Why not place it directly under "Section 1" ? Also, please provide us a Minimal Working Example featuring a compilable example of your problem.

Comment: The question as it is now is a bit unclear. Which output do you get currently, and which output do you want? What exactly do you mean by "link to Section 1"?

Comment: And also welcome to the site of course :)

Comment: what do you mean by link here, do you mean you want to make the title  a hyperlink to the previous section?  what latex markup have you used?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to LaTeX and don't exactly know the terminology.. I meant that I wanted the `\subsection{Section 1.1}` to be a subsection of Section 1 not Section 2. And I want it on a `\newpage` after `\section{Section 2}`, so I can't just write it below `\section{Section 1}`

Comment: Could [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200437/numbering-sections-subsections-etc-manually) help?

Comment: Yea that could actually be solution, to manually write the subsection numbers.. thanks

Comment: actually it didnt work... still is written under Section 2 in the `\tableofcontents` but the numbering changed tho, i.e . it's written as 1.1.... so how do I place it under Section 1 in the `\tableofcontents` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [answers to the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200480/) shows how to write section numbers manually using `\section*`, or in this case `\subsection*`.

These manually numbered sections are not added to the table of contents (ToC), but you can also add entries to the ToC yourself using the command `\addtocontents`. Note that there is also `\addcontentsline`, but that automatically adds a page number, which should also be set manually in this case.

The use of `\addtocontents` is as follows:

```
\addtocontents
{contents type} % toc (regular table of contents) or lof (list of figures), lot (list of tables) etc.
{\protect\contentsline
   {section type} % chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection etc.
   {number and name of section}
   {page number}
}
```

So we can use for example:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{1.1 Subsection of first section}{4}}
```

This line should be put at the correct position in the document, in this case below the first `\section` command that is automatically added to the ToC.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% next line only to make pages smaller for screenshot, can be removed
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,totalheight=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{1.1 Subsection of first section}{4}}
some lines
\newpage

\section{Second section}
more lines

\newpage
\subsection*{1.1 Subsection of first section}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this structure could be confusing for the reader, because the table of contents has a different order than the document itself. Additionally you need to be very careful that all numbers stay correct also when adding or removing content or moving sections around - one of the main advantages of LaTeX is that you don't have to worry about such things because everything is automatic, but with a solution such as this you don't have that advantage anymore.

Note also that when you use the `hyperref` package this code will not work, you need a bit more complex code in that case.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but you were right, it's confusing and `hyperref` doesn't work.. I changed my layout for easier navigation, so thank you for your detailed answer :)